# I can't find realm file in data folder

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm 2.2.1 for Android. I recreated the `listview` example, and the app
is persisting data correctly. I get the path of the realm file using `realm.getpath()` which is `data/data/Mypackage/files` but I can't find my realm file there. Also I changed the file name from default to `myrealm.realm`.
Here is my code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("myrealm.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
}}
```

I increased the schemaVersion to 2 but still can't figure out where my file is.

Comment: You cant find the file. What did you you use or do trying to find it?

Comment: `realm.getpath() which is data/data/Mypackage/files`. Don't believe you. It will be `/data/data/Mypackage/files`. Which is internal private memory accessable for your app only.

Comment: I need the file to transfer to mac .or send to other device

Comment: It looks as if you did not answer my question and remark.

Comment: Have you considered copying it out with your app to a folder you can access without root (but with runtime permission)?

Comment: Sorry greenapps, I searched the location of file in data/data/... using android built-in file manager ( app name is My files with folder icon). Can't we access file in non-rooted devices? If not please help me how should I access and backup it

Comment: It is /data/data/..... which is private internal memory for your app and cannot be seen/accessed by other apps and the manager you use. You will not be able to see something in /data with them as you might have expierienced.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Is there any tutorial how to send the realm file to another device for the purpose of backup or syncying?

Comment: Just close all Realm instances, use `realm.writeCopyTo()` to create a copy, and back up that copy

Comment: Did you find any solution for this case? @mobweb